# Ubuntu 17.10 small tray icons

Tags: 17.10, panel, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, notification-area

In Ubuntu 17.10 right tray icons (e.g. Telegram,Skype etc.) are very small, and  `gnome-shell-extension-top-icons-plus` does not work in 17.10.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67331/discussion-between-pomsky-and-sjb).

Answer (score 3):

You can't remove `gnome-shell-extension-appindicator`, `ubuntu-desktop` depends on it.
Solution that works for me (but You do it on your own risks):

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell-extension-appindicator
apt-get download ubuntu-desktop
sudo dpkg --install --ignore-depends=gnome-shell-extension-appindicator ubuntu-desktop_1.404_amd64.deb
```

For ignoring broken packages in Ubuntu (from this [source](http://www.sudo-juice.com/ignore-broken-packages-ubuntu-aptitude/)), run:

```
sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

This should open the file status (which can be pretty long), you now have to find the package name `ubuntu-desktop`. Now delete the dependencies `gnome-shell-extension-appindicator` from the Depends line, save the file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) and close.

Now install *[TopIcons Plus](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/)* and *[KStatusNotifierItem/AppIndicator Support](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/)*.

Comment: Nice! Now it looks like a proper answer. But one thing I want to mention, you should [never start a graphical application like gedit with normal `sudo`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications). As an alternative you may use `nano` to edit text in the command line or run `sudo -H gedit`.

Comment: If one also edits `/var/lib/dpkg/status` first, then there is no need to install `ubuntu-desktop` after the removal of appindicator. But awesome answer though.

Answer (score 2):

You may first install *TopIcons Plus* from [extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/) or its [GitHub page](https://github.com/phocean/TopIcons-plus).

But the default *Ubuntu appindicators* will not let TopIcons Plus work properly. So you will have to deactivate/remove it first.

You may deactivate Ubuntu appindicators from the *Extensions* section of *(GNOME) Tweaks* (suggested by [Charles Green](https://askubuntu.com/users/283721/charles-green)). To install Tweaks run

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

---

<sub>Alternatively if you are **absolutely sure** that you want to remove Ubuntu appindicators, then run (**not at all recommended**, it will remove `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage)</sub>

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell-extension-appindicator
```

<sub>or remove the `ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com` directory from `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.</sub>

---

Now TopIcons Plus should work as expected. You may change its settings using the indispensable GNOME Tweak Tool (aka *Tweaks*). If it is not installed, you can install it by

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Then launch GNOME Tweak Tool and change the settings of TopIcons Plus (for example **icon size**, spacing etc.) from the *Extensions* section.

Comment: not work in ubuntu 17.10

Comment: what is appindicator?

Comment: @SjB Ubuntu appindicators is an extension shipped by default which shows icons of apps like Skype, Telegram etc. on top right (in a way  an alternative to TopIcons Plus). But clearly it's not working correctly, showing tiny icons. It seems disabling it using Tweks is not enough. So I'm suggesting you to remove it and use TopIcons Plus. Try my answer.

Comment: @pomsky Rather than remove `gnome-shell-extension-appindicator`, it can be turned off in the GNOME tweak tool (Ubuntu appindicators)

Comment: @CharlesGreen I see. Thanks for the suggestion. I have added that to the answer. I suggested removing Ubuntu appindicators completely as OP confirmed more than once that [disabling it didn't do anything for them](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40640391#40640391), but now I think they didn't. Later OP said "[What is appindicator?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966383/ubuntu-17-10-small-tray-icons/966386?noredirect=1#comment1547404_966386)"!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem after upgrading from Ubuntu Gnome 17.04.
I tried a lot of fixes, but none of them helped me. I decided to reinstall Ubuntu.
After a fresh install, the issue still persists, but there is a kind of workaround that is working for me.
As described [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2017/04/fix-appindicator-not-working-for.html):
In terminal execute `export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity` then run the app `./Telegram & exit`. The result is a litte bit bigger icon in the tray and a badge indicator on the icon in the dock. [image]

Comment: it's work surprisingly!

Comment: i change in `.local/share/applications/telegramdesktop.desktop` 
`Exec=env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity /home/$user/apps/Telegram/Telegram -- %u
`

Answer (score 2):

You have to edit `/usr/share/applications/telegramdesktop.desktop` which is telegram launcher. Change line

`Exec=telegram-desktop -- %u`

to

`Exec=env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity telegram-desktop -- %u`

You can do the same workaround for Slack too.