# How to restore indicator icon size in 17.10?

Tags: indicator, 17.10

Some of the icons are uncomfortably small:

[image]

Comment: Already asked https://askubuntu.com/questions/966383/ubuntu-17-10-small-tray-icons, sadly no working solution.

Comment: And this too https://askubuntu.com/questions/966795/confused-on-the-new-tray-icon-and-dock-in-ubuntu-17-10-gnome