# Click on notification open Telegram or MEGAsynch foreground

Tags: gnome, 17.10, notification, telegram, mega

using Ubuntu 17.10, when a notification come and I click on it (email, web notification...) if I have Telegram or MEGAsynch in background (in system tray, not just minimized in panel) they get focus and open in foreground.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by myself removing `gnome-shell-extension-appindicator`, default in ubuntu 17.10, as reported [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966383/ubuntu-17-10-small-tray-icons/967149). Replacing instead with [topicon plus](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/).

Topicon plus is not affected by the issue. Moreover some application that not show icon in system tray with appindicator, works fine with topicon (like HexChat for me).

Appindicator need improvement from Canonical. Hope for Ubuntu 18.04.

Recap:

- `sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/status` remove dependencies of `gnome-shell-extension-appindicator` from `Package: ubuntu-desktop` (use search, it's long file);
- `sudo apt remove gnome-shell-extension-appindicator`
- `sudo apt-mark hold gnome-shell-extension-appindicator` to prevent future software update
- log-out, log-in back